# Foundation - Zurb Base CMS

Tags: content-management-system, zurb-foundation

Does anybody know CMS works smoothly with Foundation Zurb or easy to adjust. CMS mean MVC ZF Magento ( CMS function ) or WP class software ?

The add-on Foundation for WP is quite strange with some bugs example at the GuruSeo.pl

Thanks in advance Upiter

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is an awesome one! http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1214-foundation-5--wordpress

I'm using it for this website, just launched last week: http://evalu8ing.com

If you want IE8 support, make sure you remove all references to "rem" units in the sass files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this blank theme http://jointswp.com/ .

I already used it in http://boxlatinomagazine.com and it was not hard to work with it despite that i'm not very experienced with developing themes or child themes.

Comment: Add some essential parts from the link, Don't just paste the link.